# Reusing IPython's comm objects and widgets externally

Tags: python, ipython

IPython has a great concept of [`comm` objects](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.kernel.comm.comm.html), which are basically pairs of objects - one on Python side and the other in JavaScript - which pass messages between them allowing for underlying widget objects to be transformed in unison on the server and client sides.

I'm planning to reuse the same concept in an application I'm writing, so I'm considering simply reusing the actual implementation from IPython rather than writing one of my own. Does anyone have any experience that, and could provide me with some suggestions and caveats?